# Laravel : How do I display array data from database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have tried to fetch encoded array data from the database, but I am getting unformatted array data.

**Data that is displaying**

```
{"no_of_rounds":"Round 1"}
```

**Blade**

```
 @forelse($orders as $order)
  {{ json_encode($order->no_of_rounds,true) }}
 @endforelse
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $authUser = Auth::user();

        $orders = Item::where('email', $authUser->email)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
     
        // dd($nor);
        
        
      $currency = CurrencyHelper::getCurrencyString();
        return view('member.dashboard', compact('authUser','orders','currency'));
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $casts = [
        'no_of_rounds' => 'collection',//For collection
        'no_of_rounds' => 'array'//For array
    ];
}
```

What I am expecting to get is a formatted data array

```
Round 1
```

**Database**
[image]

Comment: I showed you how to do it right in your last question.

Comment: Use in your model cast field

Comment: protected $casts = [
        'no_of_rounds' => 'collection',//For collection
        'no_of_rounds' => 'array'//For array
    ];

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков I have done that but still getting the same issue

Comment: Provide your complete model code and controller and blade template. I will help you.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков check the update above

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have written `@forelse` instead of `@foreach`

```
 @forelse($orders as $order)
  {{ json_encode($order->no_of_rounds,true) }}
 @endforeach
```

Try:

```
 @foreach($orders as $order)
 {{ $order->no_of_rounds }}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: I am fetching an array of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. After Save, show me raw data from database

Model

```
class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $casts = [
        'no_of_rounds' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Blade

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
   @foreach ($order->no_of_rounds as $option)
      {{ $option }
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Controller save

```
$nor = array(
            'no_of_rounds' => $request->no_of_rounds,
       );
 $data= New Item();
$data->no_of_rounds = $nor;
$data->save();
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home///resources/views/member/dashboard.blade.php)`

Comment: Check for the database image above

Comment: @Dominic We don't need foreach. Comment it out. At the moment you need to: Create a new record. To keep it in the database. Then go to phpmyadmin and copy the data of the no_of_rounds field and send it to me

Comment: This is what has been posted to database `{"no_of_rounds":"Round 1"}`

Comment: And I remove foreach loop like this `{!! $order->no_of_rounds !!}` I get this error `Array to string conversion`

Comment: @Dominic Difficult to help. When you can't see the whole picture. Ideally, it's convenient for me to run and debug your code locally